# JQuery how to load next video automatically at the end of previous video?

Tags: jquery, video, youtube

i have this list of videos

```
watch?v=IcrbM1l_BoI
watch?v=t2hlcavdwrQ
watch?v=lDK9QqIzhwk
```

and i want those videos to play on full screen and load automatically the next one without exiting from full screen (like on 9gag.tv) any ideas? I attached down my code

```
<script type='text/javascript'>//<![CDATA[ 
$(window).load(function(){
$(document).ready(function(){

$('.buton_video').click( function(e){
e.preventDefault();
var URL = $(this).attr('href');
var htm = '<iframe width="738" height="450" src="http://www.youtube.com/embed/' + URL + '?wmode=transparent&rel=0&theme=light&color=white&autoplay=1" frameborder="0" allowfullscreen ></iframe>';

$('#video_div').html(htm);

return false;
});
});
});//]]>  

</script>


  <a href="IcrbM1l_BoI" class="buton_video">Avicii - Wake me up</a><br/>
<a href="t2hlcavdwrQ" class="buton_video">Ahmed Chawki feat Pitbull - HABIBI I Love You</a><br/>
<a href="lDK9QqIzhwk" class="buton_video">Bon Jovi - Livin' On A Prayer</a><br/>



<div id="video_div">
<iframe width="738" height="450" src="http://www.youtube.com/embed/IcrbM1l_BoI?wmode=transparent&rel=0&theme=light&color=white&autoplay=1" frameborder="0" allowfullscreen ></iframe>
</div>
```

Any help? Thanks!

Comment: You won't be able to access the video player in the iframe (thanks to cross-site restrictions), so you'll need to embed your own video player if you want to do this.

Comment: How to do this? Thanks!

Comment: Try something like this: http://www.videojs.com/

Comment: I've tried video.js but doesn't support videos from youtube as a playlist.